# Row sum of the matrix $P^M $ equals to $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be an $n \times n$ matrix whose row sums equal $1$.then for any positive integer $m$ the row sums of the matrix $P^m$ equal $1.$ True or false? And explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row sums of a matrix $P$ all equal $1$ iff
$$P\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}=\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}.$$
If this is true then what is
$$P^m\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}?$$

Comment: Very nice, +1 $\,$

Comment: Answer is true wright thanks u so so so much